# Licensing for Visual Studio Sharepoint 2010 solution

Tags: sharepoint-server, licensing

I had created my custom solution which is set **custom master page** on **feature activation** and remove custom master page and set **default master page** as it is on **feature deactivation**.

I have developed this solution. the problem is that I want to allow this facility for trial version for any user.

Ex. If I have deploy this solution for any site then it will expire in 30 days. after that it will ask for license key to user.

I have installed web part of "Random Quote of the Day" Sharepoint Web Part. It will installed for 30 days only. There is no timer job installed in my server. So, how they are managing the licensing for the web part. I've deploy only wsp of this web part for my server. I also need same functionality for my wsp.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

They probably have an external webservice that the webpart calls, and in those methods they store in for example SQL table when you first started using the webpart (maybee with IP or URL), and then just return an error `if (first start + 30 > Today && NotPaid)`

Comment: If there is no internet connection in my server. In this case what happen? How web service is call?

Comment: If you do the call to the webservice with javascript (ajax) instead of in the code behind, it will be the users browser that will be used and not the server. But I guess that is the same problem with "Random Quote of the day", it will not be able to retrieve the quote of you have no internet access

Comment: Do you know any other way to do licensing in sharepoint instead of web service?

Comment: SharePoint apps in the store (pay once), etc. But not any easy one

Comment: I'm thinking about to use Registry or file to store webpart deploy date time. Is it right way to do licensing?

Comment: I think there is no "right way". The problem with data stored at the customers servers or computer (like registry, property-bag values, file on disk etc), is that the customer can change the value without you having control of it. I think it is really a mather of stopping the great masses, there will always be people trying to overcome your blockages (just look at Microsofts products, or Adobe Creative Suite: people spends tremendes amounts of time to overcome the restrictions of activation).